# Javascript accessing nested properties of an object literal

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, object-literal, destructuring, client-side-scripting

I did my best not to post a duplicate topic by doing a full search on Stack including some of the suggested **Similar Questions** on right side panel of this page but could not find a decent post that could help me. Here is a partial list of my search queries:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+access+deep+object+literals (first search query)

[Javascript collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973706/javascript-collection/12973883#12973883)

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+access+nested+object+literals (second search query)

[javascript access chain with nested object literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994179/javascript-access-chain-with-nested-object-literals)

[Accessing Properties of nested Javascript literals in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632733/accessing-properties-of-nested-javascript-literals-in-a-for-loop)
)
[Javascript - Assigning multiple variables to object properties using curly braces in variable declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526065/javascript-assigning-multiple-variables-to-object-properties-using-curly-brace/10526230#10526230)

And now on to my question:

I have a collection of nested definition objects inside an array that I am having difficulty accessing so that I could build a list of anchors from it for my nav bar. I created a function to hoist the array so I can place it anywhere in my code but that is not a problem (I don't think?).

```
function hoistNav() {
    const nav = [];
    nav[0] = {text: 'HOME', att: {href: 'home.html', class: 'nav', id: 'zero'}};
    nav[1] = {text: 'POSTS', att: {href: 'posts.html', class: 'nav', id: 'one'}};
    nav[2] = {text: 'CONTACT', att: {href: 'con.html', class: 'nav', id: 'two'}};
    return nav;
}
```

I would like to create links by accessing all attributes inside obj.att like this:

```
function createAnchor(obj) {
    let el = document.createElement('a');
    el.textContent = obj.text;
    for(let key in obj.att){
        el.setAttribute(key, [key]);
    }
    return el;
}
```

I also need to create a list of links with another function but that will be ignored for simplicity. A typical sample run should be like this:

```
let nav = hoistNav();// returns an array of nested objects

let obj = nav[0];// a sample run

createAnchor(obj);// should return: <a href="home.html" class="nav" id="zero">HOME</a>
```

As it is now the above code isn't working for me. What am I doing wrong?  Also is there a *best practices* way of listing and destructuring all properties including nested ones for objects similar to this?

Comment: On your object under ```hoistNav```, you've got ```id=``` inside of the object. Don't you mean ```id:```?

Comment: `As it is now the above code isn't working for me.`   And you have no errors coming up in your console?.

Comment: "isn't working" isn't a useful problem description. What do you see instead? What have you determined using the powerful debugger built into your browser? Debugging is the **first** step (well, maybe after checking documentation for the functions you're using). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: @Keith Nice catch! I fixed the error but that was not the source of problem I am having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
el.setAttribute(key, [key]);
```

tries to set the attribute to an array containing the key as its only entry (and thus will set `href` to `"href"` since the array will get coerced to string). You probably meant

```
el.setAttribute(key, obj.att[key]);
// ------------------^^^^^^^
```

Live Example:

```js
function hoistNav() {
    const nav = [];
    nav[0] = {text: 'HOME', att: {href: 'home.html', class: 'nav', id: 'zero'}};
    nav[1] = {text: 'POSTS', att: {href: 'posts.html', class: 'nav', id: 'one'}};
    nav[2] = {text: 'CONTACT', att: {href: 'con.html', class: 'nav', id: 'two'}};
    return nav;
}

function createAnchor(obj) {
    let el = document.createElement('a');
    el.textContent = obj.text;
    for(let key in obj.att){
        el.setAttribute(key, obj.att[key]);
    }
    return el;
}

let nav = hoistNav();

let obj = nav[0];

let anchor = createAnchor(obj);
document.body.appendChild(anchor);
console.log(anchor.outerHTML);
```

---

Side note: Not quite sure what `hoistNav` is for, you could just make `nav` global to your code (but not actually global):

```js
"use strict"; // Strict mode to ensure correct handling of function decl in block

// Scoping block to avoid creating globals
{

  // Note use of literal notation
  const nav = [
    {text: 'HOME', att: {href: 'home.html', class: 'nav', id: 'zero'}},
    {text: 'POSTS', att: {href: 'posts.html', class: 'nav', id: 'one'}},
    {text: 'CONTACT', att: {href: 'con.html', class: 'nav', id: 'two'}}
  ];

  function createAnchor(obj) {
      let el = document.createElement('a');
      el.textContent = obj.text;
      for (let key in obj.att) {
          el.setAttribute(key, obj.att[key]);
      }
      return el;
  }

  // Sample run
  let obj = nav[0];
  let anchor = createAnchor(obj);
  document.body.appendChild(anchor);
  console.log(anchor.outerHTML);
}
```

Comment: So even though I did an for(let key in obj.att) I still needed explicitly point to obj.att in el.setAttribute(key, obj.att[key]);? By the way thank you so much.

Comment: @JulesManson: Yes. `key` is the name of each property in `obj.att`, so `"href"`, `"class"`, etc. You're using that fact by making it the first argument to `setAttribute`. To get the *value* of that property within the loop, you need `obj.att[key]`. (Another option would be to use the new [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries): `for (const entry of Object.entries(obj.att))` and then use `entry[0]` for the property name and `entry[1]` for the value. But what you have is fine with the change above.)

Comment: Of course. The for loop just iterates the 'key' variable over the keys of the obj.att object, what you do with them is up to you. It does nothing else by itself.